# Room finder shown as disabled if Outlook is connected to different server other than Exchange Server

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, mapi

We have MAPI addin developed for Outlook that talks with our custom server, we want to add room finder feature that will get information of available rooms, we already have server API to do that but facing issue when I try to enable Room finder feature in Outlook using our mapi connector.

This feature works if we configure exchange user. Problem is the "Room Finder" window shown as disabled in Outlook when configured user from our server.

Any idea to enable this feature using extended MAPI.

Also please let me know how to troubleshoot why the "Room Finder" window is disabled in Outlook? Or how to find which MAPI property is causing "Room Finder" window becomes disabled?

Help is much appreciated.

[Please see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrWet.png)

Answer (score 0):

Room finder is not available for POP and IMAP account.

Microsoft Exchange Add-in is required for various Exchange account features. If it was disabled or unload, you may not find the room button. To load and enable it, please go to `File` > `Options` > `Add-ins`. Choose COM add-ins in the Manage section and then click Go. Select the Microsoft Exchange Add-in and then restart Outlook to check the result.

You may find the [How to control the Room Finder in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/calendaring/room-finder) article helpful.

Comment: Thank you for response. I have checked that the Microsoft Exchange Add-in is enabled. Still facing the same issue.(Room Finder is still showing as disabled)

Comment: Does it work correctly in case of Exchange accounts?

Comment: Yes it worked correctly with Exchange accounts.

Comment: So, it confirms that the add-in supports only Exchange accounts.